# jQuery beginner: how to insert spaces between append

Tags: jquery, loops, foreach, append

I have a function that appends a number of buttons to a div with the following code and hope you can help me with two questions on this:

```
$(myDiv).append(btnTop1).append(btnTop2).append(btnTop3)...;
```

1. In total I am appending 15 buttons like the examples above. Is there a way to write this shorter instead of adding them all in a row, e.g. by using a for each loop, and if, how can I achieve this ?
2. I would like to insert one or three spaces between these buttons. How can I do this with the above function ? Would I just create variables like `varSpace1="&nbsp;"` and `varSpace3="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp"` and then append them in betweeen ?

Many thanks for any help with this.

Comment: Rather than use a space or `&nbsp;`, which is a non-detemrinistic measurement, use CSS `padding-left` or `margin-left` to set the exact gap you want.

Comment: These buttons `btnTop1`, `btnTop2`, etc.. Why don't you append them when you create them?

Comment: Did you tried using array object? perhaps JSON? It will be shorter I guess

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies. The suggestion to use CSS for the gaps is perfect - will do that. Regarding the loop, the buttons are defined in variables and are only created when someone clicks on a div so I need to append them this way.

Comment: @user2571510 Why don't you append them as they are getting created then?

Comment: Create them via JS DOM and add them in loop! Naming variables like var1,var2 is really poor quality coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use CSS rules for spacing. You can define a CSS class that you then give to your button elements.

```
.my-button {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

To add a class to your buttons, you can do it like:

```
$(yourButton).addClass('my-button');
```

You can also use an inline `class` attribute:

```
<button class="my-button">some text</button>
```

Now, without knowing exactly how the rest of your code is setup, the best improvement I can suggest when it comes to appending the multiple buttons would be to take advantage of the fact that [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) supports an array of DOM elements.

```
$(myDiv).append([btnTop1, btnTop2, btnTop3]);
```

Note that the array must contain DOM elements, not jQuery objects. If your button variables are jQuery objects, you could do the following:

```
$(myDiv).append($.map([btnTop1, btnTop2, btnTop3], function ($btn) {
    return $btn[0];
}));
```

If you can you could probably refactor your code and append the buttons as you create them:

```
var $buttonsFrag = $(document.createDocumentFragment());

$buttonsFrag.append($('<button class"my-button">text</button>'));

//...

$(myDiv).append($buttonsFrag);
```

*Note: The use of a document fragment allows to append buttons to the DOM in a single reflow.*

Comment: Sorry, one more question on this: The spacing works fine with CSS classes but when i write the array as above it doesnt append the buttons anymore - would there be another way to write the array here ?

Comment: @user2571510 Are your variables like `btnTop1` jQuery objects or they are DOM elements? They have to be DOM elements.

Comment: They are like btnTop1 objects.

Comment: @user2571510 Well that doesn't tell me much. What is the output of `console.log(btnTop1 instanceof jQuery);`? Anyway you can try the code I added to my answer, if they were jQuery objects it should not work.

Answer (score 2):

Using a space for layout purposes is non-deterministic. This means that it will look completely different one one browser to the next, and one PC to the next, depending on font rendering sizes.

A better approach would be to use CSS to set the exact gap you need. This is both more precise and a better separation of concerns.

Assuming each `btnTopX` variable is something like `<button>Click me</button>`, this will work:

```
$(myDiv).append(btnTop1).append(btnTop2).append(btnTop3);
```

```css
#myDiv button {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

If you need a larger gap for certain instances, add a class to that specific button and create a CSS selector for that element.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, this helps a lot !